# Timing chain – tag of its own or synonym with timing-belt?

Tags: discussion

I can see it both ways, many similar issues, but also differences. Do think that we should do something around a tag for timing chains, even if it is just to edit timing-belt to welcome timing chains as well.

Answer (score 3):

I say we keep both distinct: [timing-belt](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timing-belt) and [timing-chain](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timing-chain).

It is true that their job descriptions are identical but just about every other aspect of the components are different, including replacement  intervals, installation and failure mode(s).

I feel a retag session coming along...

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll add the tag and description.

Comment: Agree ... while they perform the same job, basically, they are distinct in how they do it.